# How to add template url to custom directives in codeigniter

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, angularjs-directive, using-directives

I Want to load a view file in angular custom directives as a template. my directive code

I want to know a proper way to use templates in codeigniter using angularjs.
If any farther information needed please let me know . this is my first question to this site.. thanks

## My Controller for cooks

```
class Cooks extends MX_Controller {


    /**
     * Renders an angular view.
     * @param string $pageName
     */
    function getpage($pageName){
             $this->load->view($pageName);
      }

}
```

## routing

```
$route['cooks/getPage/(:any).html']='cooks/getPage/$1';
```

## directive

```
app.directive('profileSettings',function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require:'ngModel',
        templateUrl: 'cooks/getPage/profileSettings',

      }
  });
```

Comment: You need to set a routing rule to handle this url `assets/ngPages/profileSettings.html`, then your controller will load a view and display it.

Comment: Can you please give an example of a routing rule resolving this issue?? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you have a controller called `Ng_pages`. And this controller has the `index` method that takes one parameter - `$pageName`.

```
class Ng_pages extends CI_Controller
{

    /**
     * Renders an angular view.
     * @param string $pageName
     */
    public function index($pageName)
    {
        // put here the code to check whether the requested page exists
        // and load the requested view
        $this->load->view($pageName);
    }

}
```

And the routing rule for the controller:

```
$route['ng-pages/(:any).html'] = 'Ng_pages/index/$1';
```

Also you will need to change `templateUrl` in your directive. Note you might need to set an absolute url.

```
templateUrl: 'ng-pages/profileSettings.html'
```

Comment: Thank you this works I just misplaced the `<profile-settings></profilesettings>` in my main view and sorry if i voted wrong and miss place anything anywhere i was just learning to use it.. :(